# How to prevent duplicate records in MYSQL Table when i insert data fetch from CSV file

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv

```
while (($test= fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE){
    $field1= $test[0]; 
    $field2= $test[1];
    $sql= "INSERT IGNORE into tablename(field1, field2) values('$field1','$field2')"; 
    mysql_query($sql);
}
```

I am importing data from a CSV file and then store this data into variables `$field1` , `$field2`
then I try to insert into `tablename` table. IN CSV file i have many records. My query insert the data but its inserting duplicate records i use `IGNORE` in query but its not working for me.
How Can i prevent duplication?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a primary key or a unique key in your table. Please refer to the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html).

Comment: My Table first field is AUTO INCREMENTED with UNSIGNED attribute tableID

Comment: Please post the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE your_table_name;`

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to combine duplicated rows, use `SELECT DISTINCT`.